# Missing formal parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to load a page when someone is clicking on a button, but In my console already it prints:

> missing formal paramter script.js:2:6

```
$(document).ready({
$("[data-action='openModal']").on("click", function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    var $object = $(this);

    $.ajax($object.attr("href"), {
       success: function(data) {
           $("body").append(data);
       }
    });
});
});
```

Im using https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js

Comment: `$(document).ready` expects to be given a callback function doesn't it? The error doesn't seem to match the code, but I don't see anything else glaring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing `"function"` in `$(document).ready. When document is ready it calls callback function with your code inside.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //Your code here
});
```